# Laravel/000webhost/Postman. Couldn't get any response

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, postman

I hosted my site in 000webhost. I created several api under the routes>api.php

An then I tested the api's I created usisng **POSTMAN**

RESULTS:

> **POST** api's works fine and returns json response
>
> > example: create client api
>
> **GET** api's works fine and returns json response
>
> > example: get all clients api
>
> One api the **update client api** which is a PUT api gives me this
>
> > [image]

API.PHP
>

> > Route::post('/createPlate/{id}',['as' => 'createPlate','uses' => 'PlateController@createPlate']);
> >
> > Route::post('getPlates', ['as' => 'getPlates','uses' => 'PlateController@getPlates']); //Get Plates
> >
> > Route::post('getStatus', ['as' => 'getStatus','uses' => 'StatusController@getStatus']); //Get Status
> >
> > Route::post('/getPlateStatus/{id}', ['as' => 'getPlateStatus','uses' => 'StatusController@getPlateStatus']); //Get Specific Plate Status
> >
> > Route::post('createClient',['as' => 'createClient','uses' => 'ClientController@createClient']); //Create Client
> >
> > Route::put('/updateClientInfo/{id}',['as' => 'updateClientInfo','uses' => 'ClientController@updateClientInfo']);
> >     //update client info
> >
> > Route::post('getClients', ['as' => 'getClients','uses' => 'ClientController@getClients']); //Get Clients
> >
> > Route::post('/getClientContact/{id}', ['as' => 'getClientContact','uses' => 'ClientController@getClientContact']); //Get Specific Client Contacts
> >
> > Route::post('/getClientPlates/{id}', ['as' => 'getClientPlates','uses' => 'ClientController@getClientPlates']); //Get Specific Client Contacts
> >
> > Route::post('/createContact/{id}',['as' => 'createContact','uses' => 'ContactController@createContact']); //Create Contact

Only one api does not return a response.
What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Post your routes file please

Comment: Route::put('/updateClientInfo/{id}',['as' => 'updateClientInfo','uses' => 'ClientController@updateClientInfo']);
//update client info

Comment: Route::post('createClient',['as' => 'createClient','uses' => 'ClientController@createClient']); //Create Client

Comment: Route::post('getClients', ['as' => 'getClients','uses' => 'ClientController@getClients']); //Get Clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`000webhost` does not support `put` or `delete` methods on free plans. You have to move to the premium plan for that. I'm sure this is your problem.

Comment: That's why. Thanks!